# How to fix "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'" error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a float variable from the script `PlayerHealth.cs` and use it in script `LightLevel` but I get the error message `Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'` on line 23. I don't know what to do to fix it.

I also explain what I'm trying to do near the top of the `LightLevel.cs` script in case it's needed.

**`LightLevel.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// This script is meant to get the health variable from the 'PlayerHealth.cs' script and change it to
// Intensity of the light this script is on, meaning lower the health, lower the light intensity.
// However, it's giving this error message:

// Assets\scripts\LightLevel.cs(23,18): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

// How would I fix this?

public class LightLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    Light myLight;

    public float LevelOfLight2;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().Health; // <- offending line of code
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("light level is : " + LevelOfLight2);
        myLight.intensity = LevelOfLight2 + 27f;
    }
}
```

**`PlayerHealth.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// everything in this script is working

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    // All variables
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask HurtLayer;
    public float MaxHealth = 6f;
    public float IFrame = 1f;
    private float IFrameTime = 0f;
    private bool AllowDamage = false;
    private float ActualIFrame = 0f;
    public float Health = 6f;
    public float LevelOfLight = 0f; // <- The variable I want to access from "LightLevel.cs" script
    // Set health to the max and do the math for I-frames
    void Start()
    {
        Health = MaxHealth;

        ActualIFrame = IFrame * 6f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Every frame increase IFrameTime by 0.1
        IFrameTime = IFrameTime += 0.1f;

        // If i-frame counter is higher than teh set amount, and the player is touching hurt collider, take damage.
        if (ActualIFrame < IFrameTime && hurt())
        {
            Debug.Log("ouch");
            Health = Health - 1f;
            IFrameTime = 0f;
        }

        // If the player's health runs out, display message "ded"
        if (Health == 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("ded");
        }
    }

    // Detects if the player's collider is touching the collider of something that damages.
    private bool hurt()
    {
        return Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(player.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), HurtLayer);
    }
}
```

I've tried to make the line of code:

```
player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().Health;
```

To:

```
GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().Health;
```

However, it just gave a different error message.

Comment: It depends on what you want to get as the result. Your error is definitely what it tells you - you are trying to assign float value `Health` to GameObject `player`.

Comment: in the "LightLevel" script, i need the health variable from "playerHealth" script as a float, so i can change the light intensity by that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that you've got the `float` and you're trying to assign it to something that's not suitable for holding a float (in this case, a `GameObject`)

On this line, you're telling Unity `player` is a GameObject (a regular unity object with a transform, position, name, some scripts attached, etc)

```
public GameObject player;
```

And on this line, you're telling unity to take the health value and replace the current `player` object with it...

```
player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().Health; // <- offending line of code
```

Since a `player` is a `GameObject`, it can't hold a float directly.

Note as well that because that's in the `Start()` method, it's only going to be read once at startup, then never updated again.

More likely you want to do something like this...

```
// At the top of the class, next to player
// No need to be public as you're setting and using it purely in code in this class
PlayerHealth playerHealth;
```

In your start method, you get a reference to the Health Script on the player (but not the current health value)...

```
playerHealth = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
```

Then from within your update method, you can use `playerHealth.Health` to get the current health value.

Comment: Ive tried that, now im getting this error : "Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 'PlayerHealth'. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: Apologies, typo on my part... You're missing a `()` at the end of the last snipped above, I'll edit the answer

Comment: yep, this has helped, thanks alot